# <class 'TypeError'>: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func_or_funcs'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to aggregate per ptid based on the diag_date, and calculate max, min and visit counts based on the diag_date:

```
output = df.groupby("ptid")["diag_date"].agg(Max_Pt_date="max", Min_Pt_date="min", Num_Visits="count")
output["TreatDuration"] = (output["Max_Pt_date"]-output["Min_Pt_date"]).dt.days
```

However, when I do the above (following all rules for agg) does not seem to work as I get the following error:

```
<class 'TypeError'>: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func_or_funcs'
```

Any ideas, are greatly appreciated!

Comment: The above code _should_ work if you have an up to date version of pandas. My guess is that you are using an older version which doesn't support namedAggregations. What is your `pd.__version__`, is it less than 0.25? Also the correct manual link for this instance would be [SeriesGroupBy.aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html)

Comment: @ALollz, thank you. It works in my Pycharm but when I transfer it to Dataiku, it does not work, possibly because Dataiku has an older pandas version. I am not sure I can upload pandas in Dataiku (it depends on the version). Do you any ideas whether I could do the above in a different way?

Comment: @Leonardo Yes, you can agg the Series with a list and then rename with a dictionary, so it would look like:
`df.groupby('ptid')['diag_date'].agg(['max', 'min', 'count']).rename(columns={'max': 'Max_Pt_date', ...})` (just fill out the rest of the dict)

Comment: @ALollz, thanks again. I tried that but I got an error saying that DSS (i.e. Dataiku) doesn't support dataframes containing multiple columns with the same name. Does it create multiple columns with the same name?

Comment: Hmmm, it _shouldn't_ because SeriesGroupBy.Aggregate with a list should return a DataFrame where the columns are labeled with the aggregations (in this case, 'max', 'min', 'count'). But it's possible this behavior was changed a long while ago so that may not be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my questions, after getting valuable inputs from responders above, I modified the code environment in Dataiku (which had a new Python and Pandas version) and it worked fine.