# Passing a dictionary to aggregate function in Python - Alternative Way?

Tags: python, dictionary, aggregate, databricks

I have a bit of an odd issue - the following code works in Jupyter Notebook but it does not work in Databricks:

```
df = df.set_index('date')

groups = ['ABC', 'XYZ']

df_grouped = df.groupby(groups)
df_grouped = df_grouped.resample('Q')

df_grouped_agg = dict(
    sum_area=('shop_area', 'sum'),
    total_count=('name', 'count'),
    sum_total_1=('total_cost_customer', 'sum'),
    sum_total_2=('total_cost_item', 'sum'),
)

df_grouped = df_grouped.agg(**df_grouped_agg)
```

When I run this code in Databricks, I get the following error:

`aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'`

I'm not too sure how to fix this - most answers to this issue state that updating Pandas is what fixes it, but since I'm using Databricks everything is already updated. If anyone has an idea I'd greatly appreciate it!

EDIT: This question does provide a bit more insight, but I'm not sure how to re-write my code in a similar way:

[<class 'TypeError'>: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func_or_funcs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69945059/class-typeerror-aggregate-missing-1-required-positional-argument-func-o)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this problem in the future (especially with Databricks for some reason) here's a workaround:

Basically, replace:

```
df_grouped_agg = dict(
    sum_area=('shop_area', 'sum'),
    total_count=('name', 'count'),
    sum_total_1=('total_cost_customer', 'sum'),
    sum_total_2=('total_cost_item', 'sum'),
)

df_grouped = df_grouped.agg(**df_grouped_agg)
```

with

```
df_grouped = df_grouped.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({ 
    'sum_area': x['shop_area'].sum(),
    'total_count': x['name'].count(), 
    'sum_total_1': x['total_cost_customer'].sum(),   
    'sum_total_2': x['total_cost_item'].sum()}))
```